# Unable to lauch Opera node on Selenium grid (selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to setup Selenium grid (Hub and nodes will run on same VM) which has Chrome, InternetExplorer, Firefox and Opera nodes running on it.

Im working with such infrastructure:
**OS**: Windows Server 2012 R2 (Virtual machine) will host entire grid (hub + nodes)
**Java**: Version 8 Update 111
**Browsers**: Chrome (55), Firefox (50), IE (11), Opera (42)
**Selenium server**: selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
**Opera webdriver (chromium based)**: 0.2.2 (https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases)
**Selenium tests framework**: C# (Webdriver nuget 3.0.1) tests written using Nunit framework

Problem:
I can't run selenium tests against Opera browser using RemoteWebDriver passing hub address and opera capabilities like this:

```
`RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumHubAddress, DesiredCapabilities.Opera());`
```

i get following error:

```
`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance`
```

My thought that issue may be server itself because when i start a node with following command:

`java -Dwebdriver.opera.driver=D:\SeleniumGrid\Opera\operadriver.exe -jar ../Server/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeOperaConfig.json -port 4552`

nodeOperaConfig.json is default configuration from Selenium sample (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json)

```
{
  "browserName": "opera",
  "maxInstances": 5,
  "version": 42,
  "webdriver.opera.driver" : "D:\\SeleniumGrid\\Opera\\operadriver.exe"
}
```

i see following messages in cosole:

```
19:28:14.774 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
19:28:14.774 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registrat
ion is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
19:28:14.774 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
19:28:14.774 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not re
gistered
```

i browsed documentation and other threads and i didin't found a way how to register Opera driver on my selenium grid machine.
Its the first time i'm trying to setup selenium grid (so probabbly i missconfigured something).
Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Is `com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver` on each node in the specified location: `D:\\SeleniumGrid\\Opera\\operadriver.exe`?

Comment: yes, `D:\SeleniumGrid\Opera` directory has this exe -> `operadriver.exe`

but i don't know how to instruct opera node to read it from here, maybe this line is incorrect ->   
`"webdriver.opera.driver" : "D:\\SeleniumGrid\\Opera\\operadriver.exe"`   
  
?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/zsWBJESoMO <- screenshot to show that opera driver exists at this directory

Comment: I hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277677/opera-browser-in-selenium-grid-driver-class-not-found/43325047#43325047