# Opera browser in Selenium grid: Driver class not found

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to setup an environment with Selenium grid to execute my Selenium test on a remote machine. The only browser I can`t get to work is Opera. I configured it the same as the other browsers. However when I start the node it shows a Driver class not found.

I`m Running windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit on my host computer

The node and the host are on windows 7 Enterprise 32 bit service pack 1

On the host opera is installed, the opera webdriver is in C:/GUI-Tests/Drivers/operadriver.exe, I tried the 32 bit webdriver and the 64 bit webdriver and I`m still getting the error:

```
13:30:37.169 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
13:30:37.169 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped: Unable to create new instances on this machine.
13:30:37.178 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
13:30:37.178 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
```

If anyone knows something about this problem please help me.

---

### Extra information about my environment

Starting the hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role hub -hubConfig hubConfig.json
```

My Hub config:

```
{
  "host": ip,
  "maxSessions": 5,
  "port": 4444,
  "cleanupCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets": [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 180000,
  "platform": "WINDOWS"
}
```

Starting the node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
```

My node config file:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "opera",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "webdriver.opera.driver": "C:/GUI-Tests/Drivers/operadriver.exe"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 1,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

A screenshot of the drivers location:
[image: DriverLocation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question because I discovered the answer, and I`m hoping to help everyone that googles on this question :)

Well it turns out opera driver is a legacy driver, you won't need it.

You do need the Opera browser and [operachromiumdriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases). In c# define your capabilities as:

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "operablink");
capabilities.Platform = new Platform(PlatformType.Windows);
_webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(_gridServerUri, capabilities);
```

On your node:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "operablink",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 1,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

I hope this will be useful to someone at least it was useful to me.

### Note:

- operachromiumdriver is in my path variable
- my node and hub are running Windows 7

Comment: great dude this helped me. I only used browserName: 'opera' and it din´t worked but with you capabilities it worked for me aswell

Comment: for me the node config from the question worked well. The only things I changed were that I removed the proxy key and the pass to the driver set simply as "operadriver.exe" without any prefix pass. Then created a shortcut to command prompt to start in my tests directory and the /k switch to start the node `/k java -jar selenium.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeconfig.json`